# Updating path in Vagrant using shell provisioning

Tags: ruby, linux, ubuntu, vagrant, provisioning

I am using Vagrant to deploy a virtual machine with several installed packages using shell provisioning. One of the packages needs an update of path to be used properly which I wasn't able to do.

These are the contents of my Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# Vagrantfile API/syntax version. Don't touch unless you know what you're doing!
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

config.vm.box = "precise64"
config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise64.box"

#config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8888, host: 8888

config.ssh.forward_agent = true
config.vm.provision "shell", path: "provision.sh" 

end
```

These are the following things I tried:

1. Create a separate .bashrc and .profile files with the following commands (appended at the end of file) and copy them into home directory:

   ```
   export PATH="/usr/local/x86_64/bin:$PATH"
   ```
2. Try to write into .profile file:

   ```
   echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/x86_64/bin:$PATH"' >> .profile
   ```
3. Just try exporting PATH during the provisioning (i.e. as a line of code in the provision.sh):

   ```
   export PATH="/usr/local/x86_64/bin:$PATH"
   ```

After `vagrant up` command finishes, this command does enable the change of path following `vagrant ssh`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was resolved with the following added to the `provision.sh` file based on this [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vagrant-up/wvvX7bqXcuw):

```
echo PATH $PATH
[ -f ~/.profile ] || touch ~/.profile
[ -f ~/.bash_profile ] || touch ~/.bash_profile
grep 'PATH=/usr/local/x86_64/bin' ~/.profile || echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/x86_64/bin:$PATH' | tee -a ~/.profile
grep 'PATH=/usr/local/x86_64/bin' ~/.bash_profile || echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/x86_64/bin:$PATH' | tee -a ~/.bash_profile
. ~/.profile
. ~/.bash_profile
echo PATH $PATH
```

This works for the precise 64 box all the commands should be one line.

Comment: I had a very similar problem. But in my case I had to use your script as a vagrant user, and not as root. Since vagrant defaults to root during the provision, I had to add the privileged flag: `config.vm.provision :shell, path: 'android_update.sh', priviliged: false`. PS: It is possible to use multiple shell script providers.

Answer (score 0):

Example using Ex/vi editor:

```
ex +'$s@$@\rexport PATH=/var/lib/vendor/bin:$PATH@' -cwq /etc/bash.bashrc
```

which appends:

```
export PATH=/var/lib/vendor/bin:$PATH
```

into global `/etc/bash.bashrc` file (so it's available for all users using `bash` shell, or use `/etc/profile` to use for all Bourne shells).

Alternatively use simply `cat`, e.g.:

```
cat >> ~/.bashrc <<EOF
export PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:\$PATH
EOF
```

If you need to have access to newly tool straight away, then you need to `source` the file.

If you're using `composer`, you may consider installing the binaries by specifying the requirements in `composer.json`, see some [examples here](https://superuser.com/a/977974/87805), so in this case, you don't have to worry about configuring PATH variable.

---

If you're using [Ansible playbooks](http://docs.ansible.com/), you can try using [Files Modules](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/lineinfile_module.html) with the following rule in yml file:

```
- name: Update bashrc to add new PATH entry:
    dest=/home/vagrant/.bashrc
    line="export PATH='/usr/local/x86_64/bin:$PATH'"
    regexp="^export PATH"
    owner=vagrant
    state=present
    insertafter=EOF
    create=True
```